# channels get url parameter without spaces

Tags: django, django-channels

Hi i'm fiddling with django-channels 2 and want to grab the URL parameter and use it in a function, but it seems like it contains a space or something similiar which causes issues with my function. My function takes 1 argument but when I try to pass the URL parameter in it gives me the following error `task_status() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I can see when I try to print the URL it prints the correct value but a new line is also created.

Is there any way to grab ONLY the URL parameter and be able to use it directly in a function?

```
consumers.py
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

        user = self.scope['user']
        get_task_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['task_id']
        print(get_task_id)
        get_info = await self.task_status(get_task_id)
        print(get_info)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": "hey"
        })
    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("receive", event)

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)

    def task_status(task_id):
        command = "golemcli tasks show {}".format(task_id)
        taskoutput = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        print(taskoutput)
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/dashboard/task/(?P<task_id>[0-9a-f-]+)', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

website URL `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/task/aa3c6c12-5446-11ea-b237-1e0f691c9a55`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `task_status` is a method so its first augment should be `self`, python always adds this augment to the function when you call it that is why you are getting you error. It is calling the method with `self` and with `task_id`

To fix this you should define your method like this:

```py
def task_status(self, task_id):
    ....
```

---

on another point you are waiting synchronously in your `task_status` method this will block the entire server from handling any other trafic.

You should make your `task_status` an `async` method and then use an async subprocess comand to start and `await` for the output https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#examples

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take a look into the provided resources.